# Styling Mailto Links for AOL Mail

Tags: html, css, email

Recently, AOL Mail started ignoring the coding I had been using to override their built-in link styling. The strange thing is that my coding still works for regular links, but not mailto links. Here is the workaround coding that had been working for AOL, Gmail, Outlook, and other mail services that like to insert their own styling for links:

```
<a href="mailto:fake@fakeURL" style="color:#428BCA;text-decoration: none !important;text-decoration: none;border-bottom:none !important;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">fake@fakeURL.com</strong></a>
```

Has anyone had any success to fix this new problem with mailto links in AOL?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class, like class="mail_link" to your  tag and then inside the  add a style targeting the  tag:

```
.mail_link {
    color: #428BCA !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```